# Large UML Class Diagram, multiple Aggregation/Composition/Inheritance

Tags: uml

Consider the large UML diagram below (it's not done so pls don't comment on specific details):

[image: Large Image]

*Right-Click->View Image to magnify.*

**Problem:**

Suppose, a couple base class wants to inherit the *Observable* class (left bottom). How would you go about these without cluttering the UML diagram with inheritance line? I'd like to make this as formal as possible.

Comment: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams-overview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please verify that what you really need is a wallpaper / supersized diagram ;) This is exactly the cause why you'd normally come up with several diagrams. One displays the general inheritance structure, others focus on the details of what you surrounded with the colored frames. This step of abstraction is what will really help you.
Plus, you don't need to ask your marketing agency to print it out for you.

If that still doesn't help, reconsider your architecture in terms of low coupling.

Personally I like Enterprise Architect's "slim" notation of superclasses:

[image: EstimatableWorkTask is the superclass in this example]

(`EstimatableWorkTask` is the superclass in this example)

This is tool specific, though.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Also, currently I'm using Microsoft Visio, I have heard that EA can generate code for you (good feature I guess) and its perhaps cheaper. I'll give it a shot.